# using svg path as a trigger to show div via jquery

Tags: jquery, svg

I am trying to use a SVG path to trigger a div show, but when I try to do it with jquery I am not having any luck with complex graphics

here is the sample html: http://ifelseifelse.com/public/svg/test.html

I have a fiddle working with a simple graphic, so I know its possible, not sure what I am doing wrong though http://jsfiddle.net/EzfwV/210/

```
$("#trigger").hover(function(){
    $('.hoverMe').removeClass('hidden');
},function(){
    $('.hoverMe').addClass('hidden');
});

<div class="hoverMe hidden">I was hidden</div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <path id="trigger" d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
</svg>

.hidden { display:none }
```

Comment: you should group `<g></g>` your graphics in your `svg` to give them `#trigger` otherwise you have non triggering graphics on the level above. remember: id names should be unique, but this is what you want i think. for some graphics some coming up html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your testcode has #trigger twice in its markup (once in html, once in svg) so jQuery ignores `svg #trigger` if there is another `div#trigger`. if **id** are not unique you become unexpected results or nothing happens. this comes from the lookup mechanism of jquery, id's are unique so it breaks up looking for others after first hit in your DOM

see the difference

```
$("svg #trigger").hover(function(){
    $('.hoverMe').removeClass('hidden');
  },function(){
    $('.hoverMe').addClass('hidden');
  }
);
$("div#trigger2").hover(function(){
    $('.hoverMe').removeClass('hidden2');
  },function(){
    $('.hoverMe').addClass('hidden2');
  }
);
```

Comment: and it is much easier to use `$('.tooltip').hide();` and `$('.tooltip').show();`

Comment: yeah, indeed. that was a stupid mistake. $('#trigger').length indeed returned 1. tired mistake, thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 0):

what about something like this..

```
$("path").hover(function(e){
    var tooltip=(e.target.id).split('_');
    var whichone='#tooltip'+tooltip[1];
    $(whichone).show();
});

<div id="tooltip1">I was hidden1</div>
<div id="tooltip2">I was hidden2</div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <path id="trigger_1" d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
    <path id="trigger_2" d="M40 100 L25 300 L225 100 Z" />
</svg>
```

Comment: but in this code you need something to fade out the last visible tooltip. now i'm tired too :) shat hippens.